# How to copy data from one spreadsheet to other in rust?

Tags: rust

I have some large .xlsx files. I wanted to copy data of all these xlsx file in one large file with some additional data agains each row like timestamp when the data was copied. file_name from where the data is copied etc.

I have written a code for doing so and it is working fine. But I am copying data cell by cell. Since my files are quite large I want to have some efficient method.

The code that is copying data cell by cell is as follows:

```
pub fn insert_data_from_file(
    from_file: &std::path::Path,
    to_file: &std::path::Path,
) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let file_name = from_file
        .file_name()
        .unwrap()
        .to_owned()
        .into_string()
        .unwrap();

    let mut output_ss = reader::xlsx::read(to_file).unwrap();
    let output_ws = output_ss.get_sheet_mut(&0).unwrap();

    let input_ss = reader::xlsx::read(from_file).unwrap();
    let input_ws = input_ss.get_sheet(&0).unwrap();

    let (output_ws_highest_col_index, output_ws_highest_row_index) =
        output_ws.get_highest_column_and_row();
    let (input_ws_highest_col_index, input_ws_highest_row_index) =
        input_ws.get_highest_column_and_row();

    let mut output_ws_current_row_index: u32 = 1;
    let mut output_ws_current_col_index: u32 = 1;

    let mut input_ws_current_col_index = 0;
    let mut input_ws_current_row_index = 1;

    // Insert data from file into combine spreadsheet.
    // It is copying data cell by cell.
    // I want to copy all the sheet at once or row by row
    // so that the speed can be improved.
    for cell in input_ws.get_cell_value_by_range(&input_ws.calculate_worksheet_dimension()) {
        if input_ws_current_col_index < input_ws_highest_col_index {
            input_ws_current_col_index += 1;
        } else {
            input_ws_current_col_index = 1;
            input_ws_current_row_index += 1;
        }

        if output_ws_highest_row_index == 1 || input_ws_current_row_index > 1 {
            if output_ws_current_col_index < input_ws_highest_col_index + 5 {
                output_ws_current_col_index += 1;
            } else {
                output_ws_current_col_index = 1;
                output_ws_current_row_index += 1;
            }
            output_ws
                .get_cell_value_mut((output_ws_current_col_index, output_ws_current_row_index))
                .set_value(cell.get_value());
        }
    }

    let _ = writer::xlsx::write(&output_ss, to_file);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: check out https://pola.rs, it's similar to Pandas but written in Rust and has an API you can use. With the use of dataframes, you might be able to do it more efficiently

Comment: This will only really be possible if the crate you're using to write to the xlsx file supports some kind of bulk-copy operation. More importantly, copying cell-by-cell is probably fine. Have you actually measured how long it takes for a realistic file?

Comment: Thanks Leil for the help, Let me explore that crate.

Comment: Thanks @JMAA,  I checked with three files all having 1000 rows. It has taken 10secs per file. Which seems to be quit huge time. (Although, I noticed there are some areas of improvements in my code but still it is huge time)

Comment: Like I said, bulk copying would have to be supported by the crate used to read/write xlsx files, so just read the docs for that crate to see if it's there. 10s seems like a very long time to me, 1000 rows doesn't sound like much (what's that in bytes? are you compiling with `--release`?). In any case, you can always process different files in parallel, which is likely the easiest way to get an absolute-terms speedup.

Comment: Dear Leil, can we read excel files using pola.rs?